# JMeter request rate drops every 10 minutes

Tags: performance, kubernetes, jmeter, benchmarking, jmeter-5.0

I use JMeter for HTTP-based performance testing in Kubernetes. Each JMeter instance has more than 80GB memory.

Everything works fine, but, every 10 minutes, the request rate drops from ~101Requests/Second to ~95Requests/Second:

```
summary +   3116 in 00:00:30 =  103.9/s Avg:    20 Min:     0 Max:   293 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 20 Started: 20 Finished: 0
summary =  58661 in 00:10:13 =   95.6/s Avg:    29 Min:     0 Max:  2625 Err:    23 (0.04%)
summary +   2883 in 00:00:30 =   96.0/s Avg:    24 Min:     0 Max:  2330 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 20 Started: 20 Finished: 0
summary =  61544 in 00:10:43 =   95.6/s Avg:    28 Min:     0 Max:  2625 Err:    23 (0.04%)
summary +   3097 in 00:00:30 =  103.2/s Avg:    20 Min:     0 Max:   319 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 20 Started: 20 Finished: 0
```

I have no idea why the request rate is decreasing. I also measure the latency between JMeter and the SUT, but I can't see any increasing latency or anything. Also, the HTTP response code between JMeter and the SUT is always 200. Memory usage is ~30GB, so each instance has more than enough memory. CPU usage is ~80% per instance.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say what's wrong without seeing resources consumption in Kubernetes, JMeter, your application, etc so you need to set up a proper monitoring of everything including JMeter [JVM metrics](https://dzone.com/articles/diving-into-jvm-metrics). If you don't have any monitoring toolchain you can consider using [JMeter PerfMon plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) for this.

If you need a guess - It might be due to [Garbage Collection](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html) like it's described in [Concurrent, High Throughput Performance Testing with JMeter](https://howtojboss.wordpress.com/2012/07/31/concurrent-high-throughput-performance-testing-with-jmeter/)

Answer (score 2):

Did you check the logs? Insufficient thread count could be the issue. I think you are trying to achieve constant RPS. If so, I suggest [ThroughputShapingTimer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) plugin along with [ConcurrencyThreadGroup](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/). ConcurrencyThreadGroup dynamically allocates new threads for this kind of situation. The docs I sent explain how to use it.

On the other hand, 30GB memory for 100 RPS is insane. If you are not dependent on Jmeter, I highly suggest using [ddosify](https://github.com/ddosify/ddosify). You'll probably use 3-4MB memory consumption for 100 RPS. Here is a simple command for 100 RPS:

```
ddosify -t target.com -n 1000 -d 10
```